# Check records in a column which exceeds 4000 characters

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have created a VIEW with a column containing aggregated values(stores the output in varchar2 data type). Is there a way for me to check which records exceeds the maximum limit, for example varchar2(4000)? I haven't been able to create a table due to the error "character string buffer too small". I was thinking that if I could know how many records exceed the character length, then I could probably try to use substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating a view.
It will be having a definition with the select statement

so you can

```
select <columns>,length(column you have to check)
from <tableName>
group by <columns>
having length<column> > 4000;
```

Comment: I keep getting the error that it is not a GROUP BY expression.

Comment: ok what you can try is that create a subquery for the query i have given you and then filter it based on the length.
select * from (select <columns>,length(column you have to check) len
from <tableName>
) where len > 4000;